# Inverse $n=\frac{e^x}{\log x}$

Tags: inverse-function

$$n=\frac{e^x}{\log x}$$

I've been thinking for several hours about how to find the inverse function, but I always get to a nested function.

They can help me or recommend some literature that allows me to solve this problem. In theory there is its inverse clearly not with elementary functions, I am interested in knowing and learning about new techniques for this type of functions. I appreciate the help.

Comment: you can use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem to acquire a series representation of the inverse

Comment: Using successive approximation, you can obtain an asymptotic expansion for large $n$: $$
x \sim \log n + \log \log \log n + \frac{{\log \log \log n}}{{(\log n)(\log \log n)}} +  \cdots 
$$ This gives you one of the solutions asymptotically.

Comment: @Gary Thanks can you give me a link where I can look at this.

Comment: I cannot really give you a link. If you take the logarithm of your expression and re-order, you find $x=\log n+\log\log x$. Now you substitute $x$ on the right-hand side by the whole right-hand side and do some re-expansions using things like $\log(1+w)=w-\ldots$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you!!

Comment: Note that for $n = e^{e^{W(1)}}/W(1) \approx 10.281705230887$ there is one real solution of $x=e^{W(1)}\approx 1.76322283435$ using the Lambert W-function and $W(1)\approx 0.56714329$; for smaller $n$ there are no real solutions and for larger $n$ there are two real solutions

Answer (score 1):

[Inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) isn't the right term here, because you have an equation, not a function. A function can have [partial inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_inverse#Partial_inverses), only [bijective functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) have an inverse function, and an equation can have solutions.

$$n=\frac{e^x}{\ln(x)}$$
$$n\ln(x)-e^x=0$$

We see, your equation can be rearranged to an irreducible polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($\ln(x),e^x$). We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.
I don't know if the equation has solutions in the [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number).

$$n=\frac{e^x}{\ln(x)}$$
$x\to e^z$:
for real $x,z$:
$$n=\frac{e^{e^z}}{z}$$
$$ze^{-e^z}=\frac{1}{n}$$

We see, your equation cannot be solved in terms of [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W), but in terms of Hyper Lambert W:

$$G(-1;z):=ze^{-e^z}$$
$$G(-1;z)=\frac{1}{n}$$
$$z=HW(-1;\frac{1}{n})$$
$$x=e^{HW(-1;\frac{1}{n})}$$

So we have a closed form for $x$, and the representations of Hyper Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

[Galidakis, I. N.: On solving the p-th complex auxiliary equation $f^{(p)}(z)=z$. Complex Variables 50 (2005) (13) 977-997](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233129552_On_solving_the_p-th_complex_auxiliary_equation_fpzz)

[Galidakis, I. N.: On some applications of the generalized hyper-Lambert functions. Complex Variables and Elliptic Equations 52 (2007) (12) 1101-1119](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233200491_On_some_applications_of_the_generalized_hyper-Lambert_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the largest root (when it exists), you can have a quite good approximation of it after one single iteration of Halley method starting with $x_0=\log(n)$ writing the function as
$$f(x)=x-\log(\log(x))-\log(n)$$ Using
$$L_1=\log(n) \qquad\qquad  L_2=\log(L_1)\qquad\qquad  L_3=\log(L_2)$$ we obtain
$$x_1=L_1+\frac{2 L_1 L_2L_3(L_1 L_2-1) }{2 (L_1 L_2-1)^2+(L_2+1) L_3}$$ Using this estimate, one single iteration of Newton method would give almost the solution
$$x_2=x_1+\frac{x_1 \log (x_1) (\log (n)-x_1+\log (\log (x_1)))}{x_1 \log (x_1)-1}$$

Using $n=10^k$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 k & x_1 & x_2 & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 5.09162713306291 & 5.09236408502652 &  5.09236407321316 \\
 3 & 7.61551194849834 & 7.61590897000061 &  7.61590896893251 \\
 4 & 10.0461676672324 & 10.0463804200754 &  10.0463804199298 \\
 5 & 12.4373422964443 & 12.4374674557571 &  12.4374674557281 \\
 6 & 14.8068649302967 & 14.8069444919917 &  14.8069444919841 \\
 7 & 17.1628132076291 & 17.1628668931673 &  17.1628668931649 \\
 8 & 19.5095090608892 & 19.5095470059521 &  19.5095470059513 \\
 9 & 21.8495239633877 & 21.8495517890709 &  21.8495517890705 \\
 10 & 24.1845060486885 & 24.1845270719237 &  24.1845270719235 \\
 11 & 26.5155717024025 & 26.5155879824867 &  26.5155879824866 \\
 12 & 28.8435102122394 & 28.8435230826814 &  28.8435230826813 \\
 13 & 31.1688990269469 & 31.1689093823764 &  31.1689093823764 \\
 14 & 33.4921726027437 & 33.4921810617013 &  33.4921810617012 \\
 15 & 35.8136655305610 & 35.8136725319265 &  35.8136725319265
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could even do better using the first iterate of Householder method for the generation of $x_1$ but the formula would become quite nasty.

Answer (score 0):

**Mellin Barnes Like Integral Representation:**

$\def\M{\operatorname M} \def\B{\operatorname B}$
We apply the [Mellin Inversion theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_inversion_theorem) on the exponentially decreasing branch of $f^{-1}(x)=h(x)$:

[image]

$$f(x)=-e^{-x}\ln(x)\implies h(x)=\M_x^{-1}(\M_s(h(t))$$

The Mellin transform uses $e^y$’s Maclaurin series and integration by parts:

$$\M_s(h(t))=\int_0^\infty h(t)t^{s-1}dt=\frac{(-1)^s}{s!}\int_0^1 e^{-st}\ln^s(t)dt=\Gamma(s)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-s)^n}{(n+1)^{s+1}n!}$$

Therefore:

$$\bbox[5px,border: 3.5px solid blue]{f(x)=\frac{e^x}{\ln(x)}\implies f^{-1}(x)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}(-x)^s f_{-s-1}(-s)ds,f_a(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(n+1)^ax^n}{n!}}$$

The integral of the summand nor the sum itself has a closed form yet, but $f_a(x)$ relates to the [Bell polynomial $\B_n(x)$](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html) for $a\in\Bbb N$. The Mathematica code
`InverseMellinTransform[Gamma[s]*Sum[(-s)^n/((n+1)^(s+1)n!),{n,0,b}],s,-1/x]` for large $b$ and given $x$ verifies the result:

[image]

**Series Solution:**

Using the Bell polynomial and [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) gives this series for the same branch of the inverse function:

$$\bbox[5px,border: 3.5px solid blue]{f(x)=\frac{e^x}{\ln(x)}\implies f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=1}\frac{e^\frac nx}{n!}\B_{n-1}\left(\frac nx\right)}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=FindRoot%5Be%5Ex%2Fln%28x%29%2B3%2C%7Bx%2C0.1%7D%5D%2CN%5Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+e%5E%28n%2F%28-3%29%29+BellB%28n-1%2Cn%2F%28-3%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C80%7D%5D%5D)

Comment: Note: one gets the following Ramanujan master theorem [series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B%28-x%29%5Ek%2Fk%21+sum%5B%28k%29%5En%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%5E%28-k%2B1%29+n%21%29%2C%7Bn%2C0%2C30%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C30%7D%5D) where one of the series likely has a closed as a  Bell polynomial. The result seems to be the same as that of Lagrangr reversion